# OAuth 2.0 Authentication Server with multiple Resource Servers

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement `oauth2` instead basic auth in our API's.

I've built a single authentication server and implemented an access token
validation in API #1 and API Server #2.

So my question is, how does `oauth2` work with multiple API's?

Currently I can access all API's with a single access_token, but I guess this should not really be..., or am I misunderstanding something?

And I'm not sure about the scopes parameter, this is more a permission thing and does not specify to which api's an access token should be issued.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use a single Authorization Server the scopes concept allows you to handle this: you could define a scope per API and have clients ask for one or both scopes. It is perfectly valid and practical OAuth 2.0 to issue an access token that is associated with multiple scopes (i.e. APIs in your case).

Access tokens are issued on a per-client basis so handing out different access tokens to the same client doesn't bring you any security advantage unless the two APIs are controlled by different entities. In any case, the client would have to make a difference in how it requests them, which would be done using scopes again.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. So basically I have to define on the Authorization Server whicht client_id have access to which scopes? If I will define this on the Authorization Server why would a client request a specific scope (with the scope parameter)? I know which access token was issued from which client_id and during the token validation within the api I will be able to check if the client is allowed to access scope xy named https://api1.example.com.

Comment: That's OK if it works for you but may not satisfy scenario's where an end user grants permissions to those clients or when clients may choose to require less permissions if they don't need all possible ones (e.g. temporarily or because of client side changes)

Comment: But how should I secure the access_token with different clients? 

If someone has managed to get an access_token from anther user over his service (@see http://homakov.blogspot.ch/2012/08/oauth2-one-accesstoken-to-rule-them-all.html), the access_token should only be valid for the Resource Server which the access_token was issued for.
My Resource Server (API #1) does validate the access_token during every request, but it also accept's tokens which were issued for

Comment: grml can't edit my comment above after 5min^^.
Here again:

But how should I secure the access_token with different clients? 

If someone has managed to get an access_token from anther user over his service (@see http://homakov.blogspot.ch/2012/08/oauth2-one-accesstoken-to-rule-them-all.html ), the access_token should only be valid for the Resource Server which the access_token was issued for.
I'm not sure if I can solve this using scopes. The article clearly says there aren't any solutions. (And I use only implicit grants)

Comment: adding the `client_id` and `aud` (i.e. Resource Server identifier) claims associated with the access token mitigates this so that the resource server can perform the necessary checks

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm issuing an access token with multiple scopes that span multiple resource servers controlled by different entities, which means when the client gives one RS the access token, that RS could turn around and use it to access the other RS, which is bad.  Not sure how to solve that.  Using client_id doesn't make sense to me because OAuth2 doesn't require the client to identify itself with the RS when using the AT as a Bearer token.  (Also, Hans, your link is broken.)

Comment: @odigity seems like something that should be part of the access token validation. did you find an answer?